# Multi-threaded processing using custom data generator in tensorflow2

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, data-generation, tensorflow2

I have been using a custom data generator in keras, tensorflow 1, with

```
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator, 
                    use_multiprocessing=True, epochs=epochs,
                    workers=workers, callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=2)
```

It worked great. Now when I switched to tensorflow2, I found out that multi_gpu_model(model) is no longer supported.

As suggested in the docs, I switched to tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(), since I am running on a headless server with 4 GPUs. I also switched my generator ('training_generator') to tf.data.Dataset format:

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: training_generator,
                                      output_types=((tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32), tf.float32),
                                      output_shapes=(([None, 224, 224, 3],
                                                    [None, 625],
                                                    [None, 224, 224, 3],
                                                    [None, 224, 224, 3]),
                                                    [None, 2])
                                      )
```

But how to make it run with multiple threads? Here is what I tried (both from here: https://medium.com/@nimatajbakhsh/building-multi-threaded-custom-data-pipelines-for-tensorflow-f76e9b1a32f5):

1. Wrapping it with 'map'. This works, but still runs in a single thread, since my CPU is not fully loaded and GPUs are starving.

`train_dataset = train_ds.map(lambda x,y: (x,y), num_parallel_calls=workers)`

2. Using 'interleave'

`generators = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(['Gen_0', 'Gen_1', 'Gen_2', 'Gen_3', 'Gen_4', 'Gen_5', 'Gen_6', 'Gen_7','Gen_8','Gen_9', 'Gen_10'])`

```
train_dataset = generators.interleave(lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: training_generator,
                                      output_types=((tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32), tf.float32),
                                      output_shapes=(([None, 224, 224, 3],
                                                    [None, 625],
                                                    [None, 224, 224, 3],
                                                    [None, 224, 224, 3]),
                                                    [None, 2])
                                      ),
                    
                    num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

`
This loads the CPU and feeds the GPUs well, but it seems to create copies of my dataset. All I want is to run through the whole dataset once, generating batches in parallel as was possible before in model.fit_generator()

Any help or insights are appreciated!

Comment: It's possible you need to also "prefetch" the dataset in your mapping.
train_dataset = train_ds.map(lambda x,y: (x,y), num_parallel_calls=workers).prefetch(buffer_size=1000)